# Month starting date and Ending date

Tags: python

How to get Starting Date and Ending Date, ex my Month has like this jan =`1` `year = 2013` feb =`2` `year =2013` mar =`3` `year = 2013` like this, i want like this `if i select 1 means 1-1-2013 to 31-1-2013`, how to get this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard solution, without dependences

```
>>> from datetime import datetime,timedelta
>>> month = 1 #jan
>>> day = 1
>>> year = datetime.now().year #if you want current year, year's value otherwise 
>>> dt = datetime(year,month,day)
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> if month==12:
...     year += 1
...     month = 0
>>> dt_end_month = datetime(year,month+1,day) - timedelta(days=1)
>>> dt_end_month
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 31, 0, 0)
```

Once you get datetime object, you can print it with `datetime.strftime` function

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial in `arrow` (you will have to install arrow using `pip install arrow`)

```
import arrow
a = arrow.get(month=5)
print a.ceil("month")
print a.floor("month")
```